# Is kafka consumer 0.9 backward compatible?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Is the upcoming kafka consumer 0.9.x going to be compatible with 0.8 broker?

In other words - it is possible to only switch to new consumer implementation, without touching anything else?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the documentation of [Kafka 0.9.0](http://kafka.apache.org/090/documentation.html#upgrade), you can not use the new consumer for reading data from 0.8.x brokers.
The reason is the following:

> 0.9.0.0 has an inter-broker protocol change from previous versions.

Answer (score 5):

No. In general it's recommended to upgrade brokers before clients since brokers target backwards compatibility. The 0.9 broker will work with both the 0.8 consumer and 0.9 consumer APIs but not the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

Based on this [Consumer Client Re-design](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Consumer+Client+Re-Design) wiki page which quotes,

> This would involve some **significant changes to the consumer APIs***, so we would like to collect feedback on the proposal from our community. Since the list of changes is not small, we would like to understand if some features are preferred over others, and more importantly, if some features are not required at all.

*Emphasis mine.

I didn't find anywhere specifically stating no compatibility. But using that quote and the fact that the producer in 0.8 was not compatible with the producer in 0.7, I'm assuming that they not compatible.

Answer (score 1):

I recently faced the similar issue where in my application, I had to read from kafka 0.9 and then write back to kafka 0.8. I used kafka client 0.9 in following way.

Consumer Config

```
    props.put("bootstrap.servers", "brokers_ip as comma seperated values");
    props.put("group.id", "your group id");
    props.put("key.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class.getName());
    props.put("value.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class.getName());
    props.put("enable.auto.commit", "true");
    props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", 1000);
    props.put("session.timeout.ms", 30000);
    consumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, String>(props);
    consumer.subscribe("List of topics to subscribe too");
```

Producer Config

```
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("bootstrap.servers","list of broker ips");
        props.put("metadata.broker.list", "list of broker ips");
        props.put("serializer.class", "kafka.serializer.StringEncoder");
        props.put("acks", "all");
        props.put("retries", 0);
        props.put("batch.size", 16384);
        props.put("linger.ms", 1);
        props.put("buffer.memory", 33554432);
        ProducerConfig config = new ProducerConfig(props);
        Producer<String, String> producer = new Producer<String, String>(config);
        String message = "hello world";
        KeyedMessage<String, String> data = new KeyedMessage<String, String>(topic_name, message);
        producer.send(data);
        producer.close();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: did you try `producer.flush()` ? This is a blocking call and gets stuck forever when I try to use 0.9 producer API and 0.8.1.1 broker. But `KeyedMessage` is replaced by the `ProducerRecord` in this case.

Comment: No I did not try that.

Comment: No problem. I confirmed with official mailing list. it looks like version 0.8.1.1 and 0.10.0.0 are not compatible. So had to upgrade `producers`, `kafka-cluster` and `consumers` too.

Answer (score 0):

It looks that in kafka 0.9.0 is back-ward compatibility built-in. Check http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#upgrade

Citation from documentation

> 0.9.0.0 has potential breaking changes (please review before upgrading) and an inter-broker protocol change from previous versions. For a rolling upgrade:
>
> - Update server.properties file on all brokers and add the following
>   property: inter.broker.protocol.version=0.8.2.X
> - Upgrade the brokers.
>   This can be done a broker at a time by simply bringing it down,
>   updating the code, and restarting it.
> - Once the entire cluster is
>   upgraded, bump the protocol version by editing
>   inter.broker.protocol.version and setting it to 0.9.0.0.
> - Restart the
>   brokers one by one for the new protocol version to take effect